# DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add Called unconditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Our current project is utilizing the following code snippet found online to direct users to a mobile view as required:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context => RequirementsHelper.BrowserIsMobile(context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()))
    });
```

It allows us to easily direct users to index.cshtml or index.mobile.cshtml depending on their user agent string. So far so good.

Extending off this idea, I was tempted to implement a localization engine based on DisplayModeProvider (as different versions of our sites are to look significantly different, but function almost identically.)

So my initial quick test was to create the following method:

```
protected void DisplayNZSkin()
{
    System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode("NZ")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context => true)
    });
}
```

Which I'll be able to call when I determine that the NZ skin is to show (which unfortunately relies on some database calls). The idea was that when this is called, it forces the rendering of index.nz.cshtml.

It was a bad idea. The mere existence of this method in my controller, uncalled, made all pages render their .nz versions.
Stepping through, shows that the code is always executed. The Function `(context => true)` is invoked in every page call.

What's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same Idea, so I'll put my version and let's see if it solves your problem.

I  started with this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576315/LocalizeplusyourplusMVCplusappplusbasedplusonplusa

but  changed this to use this because the filter was after the modelbinding.

```
public class ExtendedControllerFactory:DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(GetCultureFromURLOrAnythingElse());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(GetCultureFromURLOrAnythingElse());
        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
```

and this way the global.asax should have this

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ExtendedControllerFactory());

    System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode("EN")
        {
            ContextCondition = context => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("en-US", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        });
    System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode("BR")
        {
            ContextCondition = context => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("pt-BR", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        });
```

I think this should do what you want, but I never tried this in production.